# Paperclip loads image on one page, but doesn't display on another. "Missing.png"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm following the railscast for PaperClip and have ImageMagick installed.
I followed his video and code as well. The uploaded image is displayed perfectly in one view, but is missing on another view. I am essentially trying to get the same image uploaded to display on both pages instead of just one.

[image]

I get the following when I inspect the image element on chrome:

```
<img alt="Missing" src="/photos/medium/missing.png?1316405973">
```

Here's my form:

```
<%= form_for @micropost, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
  <%= f.file_field :photo %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Here's my "micropost" model since I've been following the rails tutorial

```
    class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :content, :photo, :photo_file_name, :photo_content_type,  :photo_file_size, :photo_updated_at

      belongs_to :user
      has_attached_file :photo,
            :url  => "/assets/products/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
            :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/products/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"

    validates_attachment_presence :photo
    validates_attachment_size :photo, :less_than => 5.megabytes
    validates_attachment_content_type :photo, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png'
end
```

And here's my _micropost.html.erb file with the image_tag on line 4.

****Notice that I removed the @ instance variable before the word micropost.  This is not following the example because I get a No Method Error: undefined method `photo' for nil:NilClass when I do make it into an instance variable.  After removal, I am able to get an image to display.**

```
        <tr>
      <td class="micropost">
        <span class="content"><%= micropost.content %></span>
        <%= image_tag micropost.photo.url(:medium) %>   #### This is the code added ########
        <span class="timestamp">
   ....
....
...
      </td>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
```

**However, on the feed page, I do use the @micropost instance variable otherwise I get a NameError in Pages#home, undefined local variable or method `micropost' for Class. Making it an instance variable at least shows something on the page.  This is the view with the missing image.**
feed_item.html.erb

```
   <tr>
      <td class="gravatar">
  ...
  ...
        </span>
        <span class="content"><%= feed_item.content %></span>
            <%= image_tag @micropost.photo.url(:medium) %>    #### inserted code##
        <span class="timestamp">
          Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(feed_item.created_at) %> ago.
  ....
....
      <% end %>
    </tr>
```

****EDIT**

Here's my controller code:

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
 before_filter :authenticate, :only => [:create, :destroy]
  before_filter :authorized_user, :only => :destroy


   def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(params[:micropost])
    if @micropost.save
      flash[:success] = "Blurb posted!"
      redirect_to root_path 
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'pages/home'
    end
  end
```

Anyone have a clue to what's wrong?

Comment: Where does your @microcode variable come from? Where do you set it? (code excerpt please)

Comment: I think we're going to need to see your controller code.

Comment: @nickgrim gotcha, sorry about that one.

Comment: @Marcel Jackwerth Just edited the post. Thank you both for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a missing image at `/photos/medium/missing.png`
If you want one to display

Comment: So you are essentially telling me to rename my image to "missing.png"? I tried that with no luck.  Also, I think that would cause my image on the other page to go blank.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me: (user.rb)

```
has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :small => "52x52",
:medium => "200x200>", :large=> "300x300", :thumb => "100x100>" },
                              :default_url => "missing_:style.png"
```

just place images in your assets/images folder named: missing_large.png, missing_medium.png, missing_small.png and missing_thumb.png